# syntax Highlighting on wordpress.com blog

Tags: wordpress.com-hosting, hosting, syntax-highlighting, plugin-syntaxhighlighter

I want to write code in my wordpress blog. which is hosted in wordpress.com. I need a Syntax Highlighter to show code. Can I configure/add Plugin in wordpress.com config panel ? or I do need a self hosted blog ?

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `[sourcecode]` shortcode on WordPress.com which is built in for you, no need to install or configure anything.

For example to get this results :

[image]

just wrap your code in these tags:

```
[sourcecode language="css"]
your code here
[/sourcecode]
```

you can see a list of supported languages and a few other parameters you can use with this shortcode at http://en.support.wordpress.com/code/posting-source-code/

Comment: But IT makes all my `<` and `>` to `&lt;` and `&gt;` in my C++ Code